# Table like structure using Div + bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to create a table like structure having headers in Div using Bootstrap. I am trying to have a structure created as below:

[image]

I am able to achieve this in table format, but would like to create the same in "Div" way in bootstrap.
I have tried the below code, but the data is not showing horizontally:

```
<form class='container' style='width:100%'><h2>Marks Tracker</h2>

<div class='row'>   
 <div class = 'col-xs-3'> <label class = 'control-label'>Select Session Number:</label></div>   
 <div class = 'col-xs-3'>{{sessionNumberCtrl}}</div>   
<div class = 'col-xs-3'><label class = 'control-label'>Session Between<em style='color:red'>*</em>: </label></div>   
 <div class = 'col-xs-3'>{{Team1Ctrl}} <label  class= 'control-label'> vs </label> {{Team2Ctrl}} </div>   
</div>   
 <div class='clearfix'></div>   

<div class='row'>   
<div class = 'col-xs-3'><label class = 'control-label'>Student Name:</label></div>   
<div class = 'col-xs-3'><label class = 'control-label'>Team:</label></div>   
<div class = 'col-xs-3'><label class = 'control-label'>Maths </label></div>   
<div class = 'col-xs-3'><label class = 'control-label'>Physics </label></div>   
<div class = 'col-xs-3'><label class = 'control-label'>Chemistry </label></div>   
<div class = 'col-xs-3'><label class = 'control-label'>option1 / option2</label></div>   
<div class = 'col-xs-3'><label class = 'control-label'>Total</label></div>   
</div>   
<div class='clearfix'></div>   
 </form>
```

How to create this?
Thanks

Comment: How are the headers created?

Comment: I know its been years, but posting a solution if you found any would had been great

Answer (score 0):

`col-xs-3` means the columns will take 3/12 of the container only on extra small device (width <= 768 px). You can try using `col-sm-3` (width > 768px) and see if it helps.

Comment: If you want to make a table by using bootstrap grids, you'll meet one problem that each column may not has the same height, so you probably need to set your row as a flexbox.